# Facing Many Errors in Testing OpenGL Examples

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opengl

I am testing this code: 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1824/True-OpenGL-Zooming

I do every steps said in this page :
http://surflab.cise.ufl.edu/wiki/Getting_Started_with_OpenGL_in_VisualC%2B%2B_2010 I mean this steps: 
 1. Download sample code: http://www.opengl.org/resources/code/samples/glut_examples/examples/cube.c

1. Click on create new project in Visual Studio
2. Select Win32 Console Application, type name of your project and click on OK
3. On wizard window that shows up, click Application Settings and check Empty Project, click Finish.
4. Select Add Existing Item from Project menu
5. Select all source files in sample code and click add
6. Select Properties from Project menu
7. At the top of the window, change Configuration to All Configuraitons.
8. Select Linker->Input from tree on your left.
9. In Addititonal Dependencies on right pane, add ";freeglut.lib" to the end, if you use glew, also add ";glew32.lib".
10. Click OK and select Build Solution from Debug menu
11. Run the program by hitting Ctrl+F5

but at the end I face with this errors :

Error  1   error C1189: #error :  Building MFC application with /MD[d] (CRT dll version) requires MFC shared dll version. Please #define _AFXDLL or do not use /MD[d]  E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\include\afx.h 25  1   TestOpenGL

Error   2   error C1189: #error :  Building MFC application with /MD[d] (CRT dll version) requires MFC shared dll version. Please #define _AFXDLL or do not use /MD[d]  E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\include\afx.h 25  1   TestOpenGL

Error   3   error C1189: #error :  Building MFC application with /MD[d] (CRT dll version) requires MFC shared dll version. Please #define _AFXDLL or do not use /MD[d]  E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\include\afx.h 25  1   TestOpenGL

Error   4   error C1189: #error :  Building MFC application with /MD[d] (CRT dll version) requires MFC shared dll version. Please #define _AFXDLL or do not use /MD[d]  E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\include\afx.h 25  1   TestOpenGL

Error   5   error C1189: #error :  Building MFC application with /MD[d] (CRT dll version) requires MFC shared dll version. Please #define _AFXDLL or do not use /MD[d]  E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\include\afx.h 25  1   TestOpenGL

Error   6   error C1189: #error :  Building MFC application with /MD[d] (CRT dll version) requires MFC shared dll version. Please #define _AFXDLL or do not use /MD[d]  E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\include\afx.h 25  1   TestOpenGL

Error   7   error C1189: #error :  Building MFC application with /MD[d] (CRT dll version) requires MFC shared dll version. Please #define _AFXDLL or do not use /MD[d]  E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\include\afx.h 25  1   TestOpenGL

Error   8   error C1189: #error :  Building MFC application with /MD[d] (CRT dll version) requires MFC shared dll version. Please #define _AFXDLL or do not use /MD[d]  E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\include\afx.h 25  1   TestOpenGL

Error   9   error C1189: #error :  Building MFC application with /MD[d] (CRT dll version) requires MFC shared dll version. Please #define _AFXDLL or do not use /MD[d]  E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\include\afx.h 25  1   TestOpenGL

Can you Help me to solve that?

Comment: It looks like you created MFC application instead of Win32 Console application. Try to create it again and don't check MFC support.

Comment: No; at first I created a console project and I just add this itmes to my project; but next I create an empty project and I face with this errors again;

Comment: And Now I checked it for console application and this errors are appear again :(

Comment: "Building MFC application" in your error log leaves no doubt you are building an MFC application. You should try creating a new project and selecting VC++ -> Empty Project.